# Spacetime curved by electromagnetic field and motion of particles in that curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory

Consider space filled with a radiation field or photons. Since a radiation field has energy density, it will curve spacetime according to Einstein's equations. Consider two different trajectories for

1. a neutral massive particle and second,
2. an electrically charged massive particle.

For identical initial conditions will they follow the same geodesic equation? How different will their spacetime trajectories be?
**I would like to see the governing equations** in both cases, to have a clearer understanding.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Extension_to_the_case_of_a_charged_particle

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks. Is the electromagnetic field serving a dual purpose here? By dual purpose I mean, its energy density curves spacetime as well as it supplies a source term to the geodesic equation?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.